# How to show custom error in Django?

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I am new to Django, and here is what I have do so far.

I wanted to take in CharField data and validate it as URL. I have done the following.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Small(models.Model):
    url_new = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='abc', unique=True)

def __str__(self):
        return self.url_new
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.core.validators import URLValidator
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

from .forms import SmallForm, URLForm
from .models import Small
def home(request):
    form = SmallForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        url_validate = URLValidator()
        url_new = form.cleaned_data['url_new']

        try:
            url_validate(url_new)
        except ValidationError:
            raise form.fields['url_new'].error_messages['Invalid URL']

    context = {"form": form}
        template = "home.html"
        return render(request, template, context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Small


class URLForm(forms.Form):
    url_new = forms.CharField()


class SmallForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Small
        fields = ["url_new", ]
```

so, I am able to validate the form on html page, but only when the form is empty and i click on submit button.

but when i click on submit after entering a non-url content in the form field it takes me to a new page and shows the `error_messages` which is `Invalid URL` (when debug is true).

Is there any way I can validate it and show the error message on the html page rather than showing me a debug page?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing data validation  in your form before checking if form `is_valid()`

**forms.py**

```
class SmallForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean_url_new(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['url_new']
        try:
            url_validate(data)
        except ValidationError:
            raise self.fields['url_new'].error_messages['Invalid URL']
        return data


    class Meta:
        model = Small
        fields = ('url_new', )
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SmallForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # form success logic
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        form = SmallForm()

    return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form})
```

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

Comment: I don't really understand the code in forms.py, how did you get form.cleaned_data?

Comment: Updated answer to change "form" to "self"